# using loader for css when javascript is disabled - webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-style-loader

Using style-loader and css-loader in my webpack config , below is an extract from my webpack.config.js

```
var wpconfig = {
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry : [
        './src/client/index.js'
    ]
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/assets/'
    },
    module:{
        loaders:[
            { test: /\.(jpg|gif)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000'},
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'   }

        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
    ]
};

module.exports = wpconfig ;
```

**When JS is disabled**, i can see that the styles are not getting written to the `<head>` of the  document and thus the page is rendered as plain text.

Digging around i heard about [extract-text-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin) , and changing the config a little was able to bundle the *.css files to a single `app.css` and effectively get it loaded.

Question :

- Am i right to assume that either style-loader or css-loader is failing to write the style chunks to head when JS is disabled?
- Is  using the extract-text-webpack-plugin a valid solution for this scenario?
- Are there any other ways to load CSS in such a scenario?

P.S : Just beginning with webpack , so in case of any glaring issues in webpack.config.js , do pointout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using ExtractTextPlugin for production is a valid solution indeed, so if you don't need any chunking, then it'll do fine. Also allows for the best minification of CSS.

I personally use ExtractText for production, and raw style loader in development.

Comment: Thanks . But what about the first bit? why doesn't style-loader not work when js is disabled?.

Comment: You are correct in your assumption, style-loader uses js to inject style tags - how else would they get there? ;)

Comment: Yup. Just had to confirm it :)

Comment: I was wondering the same about what happens when JS is disabled. This answers my question.